# How to place div at the bottom of another div?

Tags: html, css

How do I place the `adInfoBox1` at the bottom of the container?

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/snowman/hxXJh/

Please note that the container will not have a fixed height.

Comment: adinfoBox1 is set to expand to the height of it's container, so technically it is at the bottom of the container. At least in the link you provided.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute`.

```css
.container
{
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

.adInfoBox1 {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 457px;
  background-color: green;
}

.adRegularList .categoryList {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/hxXJh/5/

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest:

```
.adInfoBox1 {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /* attaches the element to the bottom */
    left: 0; /* attaches the element to the left-side */
    right: 0; /* attaches the element to the right-side */
    background-color : green;
}
```

The above will give the `.adInfoBox` 100% width, implicitly. This can be adjusted by removing, or amending, the `right` or `left` declarations. I removed the `float` because using `position: absolute;` will take the element out of the document flow anyway.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hxXJh/9/).

Answer (score 2):

Simple tricky solution. Div2 will be at the bottom of containerDiv.

```
<div id="containerDiv">
   <div id="div1" style="heigth:90%;"></div>
   <div id="div2">Content here...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the css of `adInfoBox1` to:

```
.adInfoBox1 {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 457px;
  background-color : green;
  bottom: 0;
}
```